# Javascript function not returning result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that is not returning a value the way I would like it to. What the function does is get information that is echoed from a PHP page (the PHP page has an SQL query) and return it. Here it the code:

```
function getValues(var1,var2) {
  $.post("http://url/to/file.php", {var1:var1,var2:var2}, function(data) {
    values = data.split(',');
    return values[0];
  });
}
```

I know that the PHP file is working because if I were to write `alert(data);` or `alert(values);` I can see the values there. When I call the function, for example, `var result = getValues(5,6);` result is undefined. Maybe it is because they are not in a list or an array? Help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You can't return out of a parent scope by returning out of a child scope. Secondly, in your given code, the `$.post` success is executed long after `getValues` returns. The structure used here simply won't work in an asynchronous nature.

Comment: did you intend `values` to be a global variable?

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because AJAX calls are asynchronous (first A of AJAX), and thus it executes a callback function, it does not return a result.

Answer (score 1):

As KayKay points out, the async method will never return any data. However, if you really must have that return, you could set 'async' to false.

Comment: As long as you plan on never upgrading jQuery past 1.8

Comment: Ah, I did not realize they planned on removing the async parameter. Good to know, thanks.